# Shell commando not working for compression photo's by TinyPNG

Tags: linux, bash, shell, image-compression

Hello guys I don't real know much about shells. 
I need to compress some PNG files and I found a bash shell script on the [web](https://github.com/RanyAlbegWein/Tinypng). The bash shell normally works with the API of [tinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/)

When I run the shell I get this error:

> bash: tinypng.sh: command not found...

I tried to run it by this method:

```
tinypng.sh  -d [DIRECTORY]/
```

I have also tried to do this:

```
bash tinypng.sh  -d [DIRECTORY]/
```

When I run that I just this info :

> NAME
>           tinypng - Shrink PNGs using tinypng.com service.
>
> SYNOPSIS
>           tinypng [-dkph] -f FILE
>
> DESCRIPTION
>           Shrink PNGs using tinypng.com service.
>
> On first execution, or if /DIRECTORY/DIRECTORY/.tinypng.apikey is not present,
>   tinypng will ask for an API key.
>
> Obtain your API key from https://tinypng.com/developers, copy and
>   paste it when prompted.
>
> OPTIONS

```
-f,--file FILE              Select a FILE to be shrinked.
    -d,--download DIRECTORY     Download all shrinked PNGs to DIRECTORY.
    -k,--key API_KEY            Use API_KEY, instead of the one stored in /DIRECTORY/DIRECTORY/.tinypng.apikey.         -p,--print                  When -d is being used, the URLs of the shrinked PNGs are not being printed to stdout.                                     Use this option to force printing even when using -d.
                                Otherwise, this option is set implicitly.
    -- FILES                    Ignore any options to come.
                                Everything after this option is considered a file.
    -h,--help                   Show this message and exit successfully.
         EXAMPLES
   Shrink foo.png, bar.png, baz.png and print the result URLs to stdout.
     $ tinypng -f foo.png -f bar.png -f baz.png
         or
     $ tinypng -- foo.png bar.png baz.png
     Shrink foo.png, bar.png, baz.png and download the result PNGs to tiny_pngs/ directory
    $ tinypng -d tiny_pngs/ -- foo.png bar.png baz.png
```

> Written by Rany Albeg Wein - rany.albeg@gmail.com

Comment: It's very clear that you need to run your command like `bash tinypng.sh  -d [DIRECTORY]/ -- fileyouwanttoshrink.png` You haven't told the script which png you are wanting to shrink. That being said, instead of relying on an outside service/computer to do this, you could install imagemagick and [resize with it's command](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) locally.

Comment: But it's possible to this `tinypng.sh  -d [DIRECTORY]/` ? Because of this:         `-d,--download DIRECTORY     Download all shrinked PNGs to DIRECTORY`

Comment: I don't want to resize my pictures I want to compress them but thanks for the info

Comment: Without digging into this script I can't say for sure since it isn't in the bit of documentation that it prints (or the git projects readme) but perhaps you could use `*.png` instead of a `?`. Not sure if it will support that. I see the need to compress and not resize that does make quite a difference since often times many strategies have to be employed dependent on the PNG to find the best compression.

Comment: The project doesn't has a readme. I made it work by setting the shell in the the folder and let it run with this command `bash tinypng.sh -d [DIRECTORY]/ -- *.png` So you can please write it as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tinypng --help` shows your solution:

`tinypng -d tiny_pngs/ -- foo.jpg bar.png baz.png`

which will shrink foo.jpg, bar.png, baz.png and download the shrinked files to tiny_pngs/ directory.